# append button title label text to textfield text

Tags: ios, swift, string, button, textfield

In my app i am having a button whose title is "IN +91" which will be changed as per selection of country code when that button tapped, a popup will come and whichever country you select it will display that country code name and the numbers like +91, +255 etc. now beside my button i have a textfield which upon click opens up a contact picker, when contact selected it will display that contact number in the text field. I want that for example if the button title label is IN +91, then i want that +91 to be appended to the contact number displayed in the textfield. how do i achieve this

My code for setting contact number to the textfield and setting country code to button title label:

//For contact selection code

```
extension NeighbourDetailsVC: CNContactPickerDelegate
{
    func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contact: CNContact)
    {
        let phoneNumbersCount = contact.phoneNumbers.count

        guard phoneNumbersCount > 0 else
        {
            dismiss(animated: true)

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Select contact doesn't have a number", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: {
                alert -> Void in

            })
            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

            return
        }

        if phoneNumbersCount == 1
        {
           setNumberFromContact(contactNumber: contact.phoneNumbers[0].value.stringValue)
        }
        else
        {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Select one of the numbers", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

            for i in 0...phoneNumbersCount-1 {
                let phoneAction = UIAlertAction(title: contact.phoneNumbers[i].value.stringValue, style: .default, handler: {
                    alert -> Void in
                    self.setNumberFromContact(contactNumber: contact.phoneNumbers[i].value.stringValue)
                })
                alertController.addAction(phoneAction)
            }
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: {
                alert -> Void in

            })
            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

            dismiss(animated: true)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func setNumberFromContact(contactNumber: String)
    {
        var contactNumber = contactNumber.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "")
        contactNumber = contactNumber.replacingOccurrences(of: "(", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: ")", with: "")
        contactNumber = contactNumber.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")

        guard contactNumber.count >= 10 else
        {
            dismiss(animated: true)
            print("selected contact doesn't have a valid number")
            return
        }

        self.mobileTxtField.text = String(contactNumber.suffix(10))
    }
}
```

//for setting button title label

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        select_code = c_code[indexPath.row]
        select_c_s_name = key[indexPath.row]

        self.countryCodeBtn.setTitle(select_c_s_name+" +"+select_code, for: .normal)

        self.get_country_data()
    }
```

Comment: you want to set contact number with apending countrycodebtn ?

Comment: Yes but only that +91 part. Means if countrybtncode is IN +91 then only +91 will be appended with the contact number displayed in textfield

Comment: And ayaz akbar bro . One more thing apart from this issue, i have a screen in which there is 3 textfield one for name,email and mobile number when i click on save button then values from this 3 textfield must be displayed in a tableview cell and the tableview cell is in popup which opens up on save button click. Which is the easiest way to achieve this . Should i take 3 different arrays for 3 textfield or single dictionary . With dictionary i dont know how to do can you help me

Comment: Pls ayaz bro help me